# implementation of max filter of each size

Tags: c++, arrays

I need your help, because for now I have no idea how to continue.

I got a task, that I need to implement in C++ for a given array.

The task is like this, for this array for example: [1,2,3,4]
I need to make a max filter with size 1-4, like this:

1. First step: performing filter of size 1 on the array , and we will get: [1,2,3,4]
2. Second step:performing filter of size 2 on the array , and we will get: [1,2,3]
3. Third step:performing filter of size 3 on the array , and we will get: [1,2]
4. Fourth step:performing filter of size 4 on the array , and we will get: [1]

After all of this, I need to perform a minimum function on each array that I filtered, and I need to return the sum of all the minimums, for example:

the minimum for first filtered array is:1
minimum for second filtered array:1
minimum for third filtered array:1
minimum for forth filtered array:1
return 1+1+1+1=4

The difficulty is that I need to execute all this program in less than 2 seconds for every array size from 1 to 1000000.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 2 seconds is a lot. Why do you think it is difficult to do it in 2 seconds? Do you have some code that takes more than 2 seconds to execute?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far

Comment: I wrote a code of this with a for loops, and for large n, it takes much more than 2 seconds, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the desired output? Is it a function that accepts an array and its size (n), and returns an array of arrays (with sizes 1,2,3,...,n)? Or this function is supposed to print each of these arrays to the terminal?

Comment: yes I will clarify, sorry that I didn't before. after I filtered the array with all the possible filter length from 1 to n, I need to perform a function that will take the minimum of each array and then I need to return the sum of all the minimums.

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: If you have a code, please edit the post and add it. It will make the problem more clear.

Comment: It's also important to see how you meassure that time and how you compile. Did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: What is your definition of a *max filtering of size x* ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this code help?

```cpp
void print(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
  for (const auto& i : vec) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename it>
it minimum(it start, it end) 
{
    auto min = start;
    for (start; start != end; ++start)
    {
        if (*start < *min)
            min = start;
    }
    return min;
}

std::vector<int> filter(const std::vector<int>& v, int size)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    for(int i=0; i <= v.size() - size; i++)
    {
        ret.push_back(*minimum(v.begin()+i, v.begin()+(i+size)));
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int filter_size = 1; filter_size <= 4; filter_size++)
    {
        const std::vector<int> filtered = filter(v, filter_size);
        print(filtered);
        sum += (*minimum(filtered.begin(), filtered.end()));
    }
    
    std::cout << "sum=" << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8                                                                                                                                                                             
1 2 3 4 5 6 7                                                                                                                                                                               
1 2 3 4 5 6                                                                                                                                                                                 
1 2 3 4 5                                                                                                                                                                                   
sum=4
```

Comment: First, thank you for spending your time. I will examine it now.